# Is Many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics considered non-mainstream on this site?

Tags: discussion

I have [asked a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/699655/is-big-bang-an-illusion) about the Many-worlds interpretation of Quantum mechanics and it was closed just 3 minutes after it was asked. Is this topic unwelcome?

**P.S.** In 2012 I made a questionnare about whether this topic should be allowed, and [it was voted positively](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1472/1186). Has anything changed in the policy since then?

Comment: Just because a question that mentions a topic gets closed as non-mainstream, that does *not* imply the entire topic is suddenly non-mainstream. While I could understand you asking "why was my question closed as non-mainstream?", I don't really understand how and why you jumped to the conclusion that it must be the many-worlds interpretation that is off-topic here.

Comment: The question in its current version is just check-my-work and as such should edited else remain closed.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero this is not check-my-work as there is no work. It is check-my-understanding.

Comment: that’s a distinction without much of a difference…

Comment: Personally I find Anixx's question interesting and relevant. As I see it, it relates directly to the time-reversed Hawking's black hole paradox. We can't be sure that the Big Bang happened, huh?  Admittedly, I have trouble making sense of some SE rules.

Comment: @AndreaAlciato The issue might be that you think there is a rule saying if a question is considered to be interesting/relevant by a user that it shouldn't be closed?

Comment: @BioPhysicist The issue is that AFAICS the question is directly and concretely  related to a widely discussed topic (Hawking's QBH argument) whose scientific legitimacy and interest are obvious.

Comment: @AndreaAlciato Right, but, as I explain in my answer below, a question being about a physics topic is not sufficient here. PSE isn't a site where any question about physics is good to go. It's a necessary condition for sure, but not a sufficient one.

Comment: @AndreaAlciato ; The combination “it seems to me…”  and “is this correct?” is a lethal way of formulating a question, interesting or not. Both items invite VTC as opinions, check-my-work, or non-mainstream.  The post can be edited to fix these issues (using for instance supportive references) so it doesn’t look like the OP is asking for an opinion on the validity of their interpretation.

Comment: The MWI was, to my own astonishment, voted as more popular (among physicists) than alternatives to it, at some large meeting or convention several years ago, but my general impression (from some commentary about the vote, on one or two physics forums that didn't include PSE) had been that the vote was sort of a joke.  However, Laura Mersini-Houghton, a rather well-respected physicist for the last couple of decades, has for years sustained what I'd call a major rag against Poincare's Recurrence Theorem (a favorite of my own), because of its conflict with the MWI.  Have a look....

Answer (score 9):

Questions about physics are not closed based on topic here. They are closed based on policy.

For example, I could ask a question about projectile motion that would be closed if it is

- a homework question asking how to do a calculation rather than a conceptual question about the physics of projectile motion
- a question asking how to design a device to track a projectile through the air
- a question just asking how to solve for $t$ in $y=v_0t+\frac12at^2$
- a vague question where it is not clear what is being asked of, such as "how often does projectile motion succeed on Earth?"
- a post that involves multiple questions about projectile motion all at once
- a question asking for opinions, such as "is projectile motion your favorite type of motion, and if not what is?", or "why is projectile motion taught to introductory physics students so often?"

Any of the closure reasons above are valid, but that wouldn't mean projectile motion is a forbidden subject here. The only subjects that are not allowed here are ones that are not about physics at all. But if you pick anything related to physics I am sure you could make a question about that topic that would remain open here (I'm sure there are edge cases, but I think you can get the point I'm making here).

Furthermore, a question being closed for whatever reason doesn't mean we think that subject is equivalent to the closure reason. For example, we don't think all projectile motion questions are off-topic homework questions.

Therefore, in your case, just because your question was closed does not mean as non-mainstream doesn't mean MWI is considered to be non-mainstream or isn't allowed on this site in general. I am sure you can find MWI questions here that were not closed.